Interpretation of SVD as basis for feature and subject space in statistics
I have some questions about real-world use of SVD in the context of statistics / machine learning. Namely, how to interpret the basis of a 'feature' and 'subject' space, and to hear more real-world examples where they are used (I have an eigenfaces example below).
Let $A$ be a $m$ x $n$ data matrix containing  $m$ 'features' and $n$ 'subjects' Each subject is measured on all $n$ features (e.g. medical exam). Alternativeily, the features may be a flattened image (e.g. picture of a face), in this case the matrix is num_pixels x num_subjects. Below we stick with the image example.
The Single value decomposition:
$A = U\Sigma V^T$
decomposes $A$ into two orthnormal matrices ($U$, $V$) and a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$. Below $V$ and $U$ are not made square with nullspace vectors.
The $U$ (m x n) form a basis of the column space of $A$ while $V$ (n x m) form a basis of the rowspace. $\Sigma$ is (n x n) with scaling factors along the diagonal.
In terms of our data-matrix intepretation, this means $U$ forms a basis for the space of all subject images. These are the 'eigenfaces'. But, what about $V$? This is like a basis for the combination of subject intensity values that make up each pixel? In laymans terms, the first component will give the most 'common' way that subjects intensity values vary across a single pixel location? I am having trouble visualising this.
It would also be great to hear other real-world examples of how SVD is used to make a basis of featurea and subject spaces, I'm having a hard time finding these. Thanks!

The size of the matrices given by you are not correct. Suppose $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. The SVD of $A$ is $U\Sigma V^\mathsf T$ where $U\in\mathbb R^{m\times r}$, $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{r\times r}$ and $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times r}$ and $r$ is the rank of $A$. Alternatively, $U\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$, $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. The former is "compact SVD" and the latter is "full SVD".
Consider a specific example. Suppose there is a user-item matrix of size $m\times n$, where $m$ is the number of users and $n$ is the number of items. After operating SVD, the matrix $U$ of $r$ columns now represents the user features, and $V$ of $r$ columns represents the item features. The singular values in $\Sigma$ represent the importance of these features.
The $j$-th column of $U$ can be viewed as the preference of each user for feature $j$, so if you want to know the preference of user $i$ for feature $j$, just check $u_{ij}$. Similarly, the $j$-th column of $V$ can be viewed as the score of each item for feature $j$, so if you want to know the score of item $i$ for feature $j$, just check $v_{ij}$. In other words, you can invest item $i$ by looking at the score of all $r$ features through the $i$-th row of $V$. Also, you can know what features the user $i$ value most through the $i$-th row of $U$.
